# How reduce function work with operators in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already import this

```
from functools import reduce

import operator
```

when i try this

```
>>> print(reduce(operator.or_, \[2,4,5]))

7

>>> print(reduce(operator.or_, \[2,4,6]))

6

>>> print(reduce(operator.or_, \[2,3,6]))

7

>>> print(reduce(operator.or_, \[2,3,8]))

8
```

I'm pretty confused, i dont know how does exactly it work ?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? Could you tell us what you were expecting? To get more information about the `reduce` function, I would recommend to read https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/

Answer (score 0):

Reduce applies the bitwise OR operator to each successive pair of elements in the input array. For example in your first case, it starts with 2 and 4. Bitwise OR on 2 (010 in binary) and 4 (100) gives 6 (110). The bitwise OR is then applied to 6 i.e. result of computation and 5 (101) i.e. the next element in the array, resulting in 7 (111). Similarly for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`operator.or_` is a bitwise operation, so

```
reduce(operator.or_, [2,4,5])
```

is

```
2 | 4 | 5
```

which is

```
2 = 010
4 = 100
5 = 101
-------
7 = 111
```

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent of `or` in `operator` module, so:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, [2,4,5])
2
```